# Term taxonomy child from first and second level menu

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I have a drupal commerce with taxonomy which have child.The menu was generate automatically.
Exemple:

```
Vehicle
      |-->4 wheel
                |-->car
                |-->bus
      |-->2 wheel
                |-->motorbike
                |-->bicycle
```

I want to display a link "4 wheel" and a "link 2 wheel" when we are on the "Vehicle" page (which don't have product inside) 
And I want to display "motorbike" and "bicycle" when we are on the "2 wheel" page (which don't have product inside).

I have a drupal commerce default content display and the default views product_category.
I found this video which make me make a new view call catalog which does exactly what I want (video at 15:18). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1jqu8JnLbU
But the main menu (automatically generated) still going to product_category. So now if I want a can make a menu and add every link by my hands but I don't like bad work.

So my question is how can I say to drupal commerce: "Hey now stop using the default view which is call product_category and use my view which is call catalog.
Or
How can I configure the product_category view to display all the child taxonomy like I explain.

I found many stuff but nothing very helpful
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-entity-views-attach-module
The path module
The PHP filter with code
Try to make a block this context filter and display it ...

If someone can help It will be nice !

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it. It's not the best way but it's a way which is enough clean for me for now .
It's with [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.
I made 2 blocks with this module and I configure it on a specific page.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rku2vHqZP4

If you want you can also use Pathauto module to generate nice url so you don't need to configure  on evry specific page but on every page with a specific URL like www.yoursite/Vehicle/*.

To configure that go to admin/config/search/path/settings and set the Slash (/) option to "Do not Replace" under "Punctuation" then go to the taxonomy path which you need and put `[term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]` the URL will be like www.yoursite/Vehicle/4-wheel/car.

Hope that help.